# What is VB doing when it says Updating Project Information?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Here's a dialog box which runs for approximately 16 projects and takes over 5 minutes to complete (in total).

Can anyone tell me what it's doing and how to make it stop?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer, thanks to Alexandre DeFalque.

VB is converting old VB6 modules(modulename.vb) into static classes for use by .NET.  This can take quite a while.

I had previously scoured the Internet looking for an answer to this; hopefully someone else has now been saved that bother.